# Looking for "simple" integer linear programming source code / pseudo code

Tags: integer, pseudocode, linear-programming

I may need to implement Integer Linear Programming today and I am wondering if there are any pseudo codes or relatively pain-free (well commented) source codes that explain how to implement it? With strong preference towards pseudo code.

Please note, I am not looking for a serious complete project with all the "fine tuning" to get the most optimal performance. I am looking for the most basic solver that demonstrates how integer linear programming works vs. trying all the options one by one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is a big ask, so let me try it step-by-step:

When you say **Integer Linear Program**, I assume you mean IP's with linear constraints and objective function.

**1. Start with the Simplex Algorithm.**
(Even though this will NOT work for IP's, except in "lucky" cases where your linear program has the "integrality" property.) But the *Simplex* is always a good place to start, esp. since you are interested in a first principles approach

Surprisingly, PseudoCode is not that easy to find, though solved examples are plentiful.
[Here's one example](http://pages.intnet.mu/cueboy/education/notes/algebra/simplex.htm) of the steps in the Simplex algorithm. (Not Psuedo code)

In Section [3.1.4 Summary of Computation Procedure](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/~wei/lpch3.pdf) there is something close to pseudo-code.

[This document](http://www.math.ucf.edu/~xli/Simplex%20Method%202010.pdf) also has a summary of the Simplex Algorithm that can be implemented, esp. if you follow the example in the preceding sections.

**Note** that Simplex is one of those algorithms that is relative easy to understand (esp. step-by-step) but notoriously difficult to implement. A [really good discussion](http://www.or-exchange.com/questions/961/why-is-it-hard-to-implement-the-simplex-algorithm) of why this is so can be found here.

**2. Integer Programming - The "simplest" case.**
Many people tend to start with the ["Knapsack" problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

You can find both the [pseudo-code and a Java implementation here](http://jhave.org/learner/misc/knapsack/knapsack.shtml).

**3. IP's of increasing difficulty/complexity.**

- Capital Budgeting Problem
- Assignment Problems
- Transportation Problems

**4. General Purpose vs Specialized**
You now have a choice:

- 4a. You can build 'general purpose' IP Solver (but will take a very long time to run)
- 4b. Build special purpose IP solvers for special types of problems.

For 4a: You can assume 0/1 variables and demonstrate **branch-and-bound techniques**. You can find implementations of trees and modify for your own purposes. (Essentially, clever implementations of exhaustive searches.)

For 4b: You could take one case, say the **Assignment Problem**, for which the **Hungarian algorithm** is often used since it is easy to understand and can be taught in one sitting to a group of students.
[This tutorial in topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=hungarianAlgorithm) covers it quite extensively with the math, pseudo and real code.

Long answer, but I hope this is along the lines of what you are hoping for.

Comment: Hi Ram Narashimhan, I am familiar with the simplex algo, we learn it in tau and I think I can find a document. I remember how it works. The answer is very good and well thought and explained.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite Thanks. I wasn't exactly sure as to what your end goal was. If this is not what you are looking for, just clarify your needs and I can give you more pointers.

Comment: I thought it was like Linear Programming and Simplex where there is a well known algorithm that handles this situation more effectively than exhaustive searches. (even though it is npc). I used lpsolver in the past, it is a milp with good capabilities for ilp solving (much faster than trying all the options) and I was impressed. I guess I was hoping the implementation of a generic ilp solver was as simple as Simplex is to understand.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite IP Solvers are not as simple, esp. if you are looking for something simple. If you are even somewhat familiar with R, I'd recommend that you look into the `optim` package. R code is exposed, so one can always learn something from looking at the code.

Comment: I kind of feel like the guy that asked for a simple implementation of a fast 3d physics engine a couple of days ago in gamedev se. I am glad you answered my question, I am all the wiser for it. I suspected this was not a trivial solver to implement.